# jquery datepicker defaultDate going to 23/02/2016?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've added the detaultDate to my datepicker, it is getting the default date from a database, if i look at the source code of my page when ran the defaultDate looks fine but it goes to a completely different date, date format is dd/mm/yyyy.

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    defaultDate: '01/05/2010',
    duration: 'fast'
});
```

I've also tried:

```
var defaultDate = $( "#date" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );
$( "#date" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", "01/05/2010" );
```

but instead of going to 01/05/2010 it goes to 23/02/2016.

It works fine if i use +7 or something but not a full date.

Any one got any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `yy` instead of `yyyy` per the [API](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)? Can you provide a demo?